# Creating the linear layout and other stuff on that depending on number of users

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

**Problem Statement:-**

I am working on the `android project` in which I need to create the `Bottom Half part of the android screen dynamically` depending on the `Markers (Users) on the Map`. So I divided the `android screen` in two half. In the `Top Half` I am showing the `Google Maps` which is working fine. And in the `Bottom Half` I need to `dynamically` create the `linear layout` and few other stuff on the linear layout. I have created an `image using Paint` just to make people understand how I need my UI. So currently I have shown `only one Linear Layout example` in the `bottom half` just for one user. I need same thing for `n number of users` with `Scrollable.` Suppose if I need to draw two times (two user's are there) , then in the bottom half same thing will be there two times in the scrollable mode. And if I need to draw three times, then in the bottom half it should be there three times.

[image]

Below is the code where I need to add my dynamic layout code.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> response) {

        if (response!=null) {
        // Need to create here dynamically the linear layout.
        }

        for(User user : response){

        // In this loop, I am showing all the user's on the google maps

        }


    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. And what should be XML file for this case.

Currently the XML that I have is below which is a simple UI without the proper bottom half part as I have shown in my image-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:apiKey="0vAX8Xe9xjo5gkFNEEIH7KdHkNZNJWNnsjUPKkQ" 
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:enabled="true" /> 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="TextView" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:**

In the bottom half part, I need an image and some text next to an image like Name etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do the layout dynamically... You can just use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) on the bottom half of your layout, and set the map to the top half.. Then when you get your user list, add as many of the users to the adapter as you end up needing. You can return the current view you have for a user to display each item in the list.  Here is a brief example..

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

     ListView mListView;
     ArrayAdapter<User> mAdapter;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

          //get the listview from xml. I think you know how to layout half and half...
          mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
          mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(this,R.id.userviewlayout){

               @Override
               public View getView(){
                    //here is where you add the code to inflate and display a view for a single user
               }
          };

          for(User user : Users)
               mAdapter.add(user);

          mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, Can you show me an example basis on the ListView fulfilling my requirements, It will be of great help for me to understand the whole thing as I am new to Android stuff.

Comment: See edit.. it is quite a bit of work to write out every detail including layouts.. so I am assuming you understand how to write a layout that has two halves. You need to declare one half as a ListView and return the view you want to display for the getView() function.. that is something I cannot do for you.